# bash - how to properly read an input file which values are in an array

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I'm trying to write a script that reads a file (more than one line)
which is "#" separated and putting them in an array so I can match some values.

Example input file:

```
us-east#1-1#abcdefg1234Ad
us-west#1-3#654kjhytgr
us-east#1-4#lkjhg765
```

What I'm trying to do is read through each line
and give me the match based on my input param ($1).
I'm stuck as its just evaluating the first line only.

Here's my code:  (to execute: **./myscript.sh us-east-1-3**)

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
set -x
cluster=$1

KEY=./.keyfile

while IFS=#
declare -a arr=($(< $KEY)); do
if [[ ${arr[0]}-${arr[1]} == $1 ]]; then
    echo "We have a match"
 else
    echo "No match"
    exit 1
fi
done

set +x
```

Comment: You can read the data in keyfile into the array arr with "readarray arr < keyfile"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm stuck as its just evaluating the first line only.

Because in your `else` block you have `exit` statement, suppose if line does not match, loop will be terminated due to `exit 1`, so further iteration will not take place.

After reading first line, `us-east-1-1` is not equal to `us-east-1-3`, Boolean `false`, so in your `else` block you have `exit` statement, so termination

```
+ cluster=us-east-1-3
+ KEY=./file
+ IFS='#'
+ arr=($(< $KEY))
+ declare -a arr
+ [[ us-east-1-1 == us-east-1-3 ]]
+ echo 'No match'                  
No match
+ exit 1
```

**You can modify like below so that you will use less resource, read line by line instead of reading entire file into array**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ cat t.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x
cluster="$1"

while IFS=# read -r  field1 field2 restother; do
if [[ "$field1-$field2" == $1 ]]; then
    echo "We have a match"
 else
    echo "No match"
fi
done < "file"

set +x
```

**Output `when cluster=us-east-1-3`**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ bash t.sh us-east-1-3
+ cluster=us-east-1-3
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ [[ us-east-1-1 == us-east-1-3 ]]
+ echo 'No match'
No match
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ [[ us-west-1-3 == us-east-1-3 ]]
+ echo 'No match'
No match
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ [[ us-east-1-4 == us-east-1-3 ]]
+ echo 'No match'
No match
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ set +x
```

**Output `when cluster=us-west-1-3`**

```
[akshay@localhost tmp]$ bash t.sh us-west-1-3
+ cluster=us-west-1-3
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ [[ us-east-1-1 == us-west-1-3 ]]
+ echo 'No match'
No match
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ [[ us-west-1-3 == us-west-1-3 ]]
+ echo 'We have a match'
We have a match
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ [[ us-east-1-4 == us-west-1-3 ]]
+ echo 'No match'
No match
+ IFS='#'
+ read -r field1 field2 restother
+ set +x
```

You can use `awk` for this type of purpose, reasonably faster too

**Here is some example**

```
$ cat file 
us-east#1-1#abcdefg1234Ad
us-west#1-3#654kjhytgr
us-east#1-4#lkjhg765
```

**Output (when `cluster="us-east-1-3"`)**

```
$ awk -F'#' -v cluster="us-east-1-3"  '{ print (cluster==$1"-"$2)? "We have a match": "No match"}' file
No match
No match
No match
```

**Output (when `cluster="us-west-1-3"`)**

```
$ awk -F'#' -v cluster="us-west-1-3"  '{ print (cluster==$1"-"$2)? "We have a match": "No match"}' file
No match
We have a match
No match
```

Comment: great input. I appreciate it and thanks for showing another solution using `awk`. I could use that.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Akshay that this is a good problem to solve with awk. However, if you really want to do it with shell alone, it's not difficult:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cluster="$1"
keyfile=keyfile.txt

ret=0
while IFS='#' read -r one two three; do
  if [[ "${one}-${two}" = "$cluster" ]]; then
    echo "match"
  else
    echo "no match"
    ret=1
  fi
done < "$keyfile"

exit $ret
```

The key difference is that this is using `read` to process a stream of input that is handed to the `while` loop, rather than re-evaluating the `$(< $keyfile)` expression for each run of the loop (which I would expect would give you the first line for each run).

Comment: this fixes my current script and I will take into account using `awk` to solve this. Thank you.